# Why does switch_to use push+jmp+ret to change EIP, instead of jmp directly?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86

In [`linux/arch/x86/include/asm/switch_to.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6/source/arch/x86/include/asm/switch_to.h#L27), there's the definition of the macro `switch_to`, the key lines which do the real thread switch miracle read like this (until Linux 4.7 when it changed):

```
asm volatile("pushfl\n\t"       /* save    flags */ \
              pushl %%ebp\n\t"      /* save    EBP   */ \
              "movl %%esp,%[prev_sp]\n\t"   /* save    ESP   */ \
              "movl %[next_sp],%%esp\n\t"   /* restore ESP   */ \
              "movl $1f,%[prev_ip]\n\t" /* save    EIP   */ \
              "pushl %[next_ip]\n\t"    /* restore EIP   */ \
              __switch_canary                   \
              "jmp __switch_to\n"   /* regparm call  */ \
              "1:\t"                        \
              "popl %%ebp\n\t"      /* restore EBP   */ \
              "popfl\n"         /* restore flags */ \
```

The named operands have memory constraints like `[prev_sp] "=m" (prev->thread.sp)`.  `__switch_canary` is defined to nothing unless `CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR` is defined (then it's a load and store using `%ebx`).

I understand how it works, like the kernel stack pointer backup/restore, and how the `push next->eip` and `jmp __switch_to` with a `ret` instruction at the end of the function, which is actually a "fake" call instruction matched with a real `ret` instruction, and effectively make the `next->eip` the return point of the next thread.

What I don't understand is, why the hack? Why not just `call __switch_to`, then after it `ret`, `jmp` to `next->eip`, which is more clean and reader-friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two reasons for doing it this way.

One is to allow complete flexibility of operand/register allocation for `[next_ip]`. If you want to be able to do the `jmp %[next_ip]` *after* the `call __switch_to` then it is necessary to have `%[next_ip]` allocated to a *nonvolatile register* (i.e. one that, by the ABI definitions, will *retain its value* when making a function call).

That introduces a restriction in the compiler's ability to optimize, and the resulting code for `context_switch()` (the 'caller' - where `switch_to()` is used) might not be as good as could be. But for what benefit ?

Well - that's where the second reason comes in, none, really, because `call __switch_to` would be equivalent to:

```
pushl 1f
jmp __switch_to
1: jmp %[next_ip]
```

i.e. it pushes the return address; you'd end up with a sequence `push`/`jmp` (`== call`)/`ret`/`jmp` while if you do not want to return to this place (and this code doesn't), you save on code branches by "faking" a call because you'd only have to do `push`/`jmp`/`ret`. The code makes itself *tail recursive* here.

Yes, it's a small optimization, but avoiding a branch reduces latency and latency is critical for context switches.

Comment: But wouldn't it effectively kill the return-prediction stack?

Comment: yes - but the `jmp` to register target does that as well, as you _never_ want to return to `switch_to()`, really (until the next context switch). No difference between both as far as that.

Comment: @harold: Good point; the current contents of the return-address predictor stack are valuable after the context switch for the return from `context_switch()` ([in `kernel/sched/core.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2752)), and maybe a couple levels back up the call stack into the scheduler (until their backtraces diverge).  But that's only true if `%[next_ip]` is always/usually inside switch_to; it does set `prev_ip` that way, but maybe that's not the most common value (kernel pre-emption can probably leave it somewhere else?)

Comment: But the main value of the return-prediction stack is for functions near the bottom of the call tree that are repeatedly called inside medium-sized loops.  A mismatched call/ret causes at most 16 future mispredicts on the way back up the call tree, and fewer if more `call` instructions bump some of the mismatched entries out of the stack before you return that far up.